# Зачем нужен connect в React-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Зачем нужен `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(IndexPageContainer);`

Когда можно просто использовать хук `useDispatch()` и `useSelector()`?

Ведь `provider` все равно предоставляет доступ компонентам ко всем `reducers`

Answer (score -1):

connect нужен для использования в классовых компонентах где нельзя использовать хуки `useDispatch()` и `useSelector()`